# DisplaySettingsChanged SytemEvent NotFiring In IIS or WindowsService

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

SystemEvent for DisplayEventChanged not firing in Asp.Net Core API after publishing in IIS although works normal in visual studio or ran by executable but same same issues goes if ran as windows service. can trace the issue why events are not firing in through IIS or windows service

## In Startup.cs

Registering Events

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += Helper.Common.SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged;

            Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanging += Helper.Common.SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanging;

        }
```

## In Common.cs

main logic so the controller can read the value from static variable

```
public static class Common
    {
        public static bool SecondaryDisplay = false;

        public static void ToogleDisplaySettings()
        {
            if (SecondaryDisplay)
            {
                SecondaryDisplay = false;
            }
            else
            {
                SecondaryDisplay = true;
            }
        }

        public static void SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ToogleDisplaySettings();
            Console.WriteLine("Display settings have been changed.");
        }

        public static void SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanging(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Display settings are changing now...");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to handle display settings on the **server**?

Comment: its an IOT task for monitering